# Why this syntax error in function conway's game of life in Python?

Tags: python, function, syntax-error, conways-game-of-life

I'm programming Conway's game of life in Python but stumbled upon a weird syntax error. It's in the first function i'm defining. It sais that nextnext in nextnext= [] in wrong. If i take that out the : after the for loop also gives a synthax error. I tried the function in a seperate file and it worked fine there so i really don't know what i'm doing wrong.

```
TIME = 100
life = []           # create list 'life'
life.append(seed)   # add seed to life

numrows = len(seed)         # calculate number of rows
numcolumns = len(seed[0])   # calculate number of columns
current = seed              # make seed the first current(matrix you're starting off with in each step)
nextnext = []

def create_empty_universum (seed):
    numrows = len(seed)         # calculate number of rows
    numcolumns = len(seed[0]    # calculate number of columns
    nextnext = []               # create empty list next
    for i in range(numrows):    # define number of rows in nextnext
        nextnext.append([0] * numcolumns)  # define number of columns in nextnext
    return nextnext

def compute_new_value(nextnext,row,column):    
    neighbors = 0                                 # start counter 'neighbors' with 0
    if current[row][(column+1)%numcolumns] == 1:  # if neighboring cell has a value of 1
        neighbors += 1                            # add 1 to neighbors
    if current[row][(column-1)%numcolumns] == 1:  # if neighboring cell has a value of 1        
        neighbors += 1                            # add 1 to neighbors      
    if current[(row-1)%numrows][column] == 1:     # if neighboring cell has a value of 1
        neighbors += 1                            # add 1 to neighbors      
    if current[(row+1)%numrows][column] == 1:     # if neighboring cell has a value of 1 
        neighbors +=1                             # add 1 to neighbors      
    if current[(row+1)%numrows][(column+1)%numcolumns] == 1:  # if neighboring cell has a value of 1
        neighbors +=1                                         # add 1 to neighbors 
    if current[(row-1)%numrows][(column+1)%numcolumns] == 1:  # if neighboring cell has a value of 1
        neighbors += 1                                        # add 1 to neighbors 
    if current[(row-1)%numrows][(column-1)%numcolumns] == 1:  # if neighboring cell has a value of 1
        neighbors += 1                                        # add 1 to neighbors 
    if current[(row+1)%numrows][(column-1)%numcolumns] == 1:  # if neighboring cell has a value of 1
        neighbors +=1                                         # add 1 to neighbors 
    if current[row][column] == 1:               # in case a target cell has a value of 1:
        if neighbors < 2:                       # if the number of neighbors is smaller than 2
            nextnext[row][column] = 0           # value of target cell becomes 0 in nextnext
        elif neighbors == 2 or neighbors == 3:  # if the number of neighbors is 2 or 3
            nextnext[row][column] = 1           # value of target cell stays 1 in nextnext
        elif neighbors > 3:                     # if the number of neigbors is higher than 3
            nextnext[row][column] = 0           # value of target cell becomes 0 in nextnext
    elif current [row][column] == 0:            # in case a target cell has a value of 0:
        if neighbors == 3:                      # if the number of neighbors is 3
            nextnext[row][column] = 1           # value of target cell becomes 1 in       nextnext
         elif neighbors != 3:                    # if the number of neigbors isn't 3
            nextnext[row][column] = 0           # value of target cell stays 0 in nextnext
    return nextnext

for t in range(TIME):    # determine amount of times the loop will
    nextnext = create_empty_universum(seed)
    for row in range(numrows):              # for each
            for column in range(numcolumns):    # for each column 

                nextnext = compute_new_value(nextnext,row,column)


current = nextnext     # make nextnext matrix the current matrix for the next step 
life.append(current)   # add current to life


import show
show.show(life, SIZE=10)
```

Comment: Please post the whole error - it gives information that is useful in debugging. That stack trace contains the location of the error in your code, for example.

Comment: Also *If i take that out the : after the for loop also gives a synthax error.* - why would you *not* get a syntax error if you removed a necessary part of the code?

Comment: Anytime you have a syntaxerror you don't understand, make sure you've closed your parenthesis/brackets/braces in the preceding line.  That is almost always the source of these errors

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a closing parenthesis on the preceding line:

```
numcolumns = len(seed[0]    # calculate number of columns
# missing )   ----------^
nextnext = []               # create empty list next
```

When you get a Python syntax error and you cannot spot it, look at the *previous* line to see if your brackets, braces and parenthesis are balanced.

Comment: Wow, that was really stupid. :) I fixed that but the program still doesn't do what it's supposed to do...

Comment: @user2162627: updated to fix a classic error in your code too.

Comment: Actually, I think `[0] * numcolumns` is fine here -- that's simply `[0,0,...,0]`.  If the -- multiplicand?  whatever the word is -- were something else, there could have been problems, of course.

Comment: @DSM: Ah, of course, removing that.